# Flutter http not working when having a call in Teams

Tags: flutter, rest, http

Flutter http not working when having a call in Teams apps.But if we are going stop call it will work, already check the ip address its still same.
The endpoint im trying to call in http is also from my local.

Error

```
Error fetching products: ClientException with SocketException: Connection failed
```